# How to know if a TabHost has data yet?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm having problems to clear a TabHost (programmatically). I use this:

```
tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
tabs.clearAllTabs();
```

but I receive a null pointer exception because the first time that enters the activity, the tabs aren't fills yet.

What I can do to solve this? Is there any method to check if tabhost has data?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(tabs.getTabWidget().getTabCount() > 0){
    // has data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Via this you can check weather the activity calls for very first time or not. Try this!

```
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                    boolean previouslyStarted = prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_previously_started), false);
                    if(!previouslyStarted){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                    edit.putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_previously_started), Boolean.TRUE);
                                edit.commit();
                               //Activity calls for very first time

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Activity already started
                    }
```